# USB Debugging in Windows 10 to tablet?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, device-driver

I am developing an application windows 10 on a stationary PC. I also have a tablet windows 10 that once connected to the PC via USB not see debugging (
How to make it accessible?

Comment: you could use remote debugging, I find it quite useful, have a look in here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441469.aspx

Comment: thank. It worked through wi-fi. But through the usb, it is impossible (
I would like to through the USB

Comment: Did you ever manage to debug via USB cable?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I found an article that highlights how to debug a UWP application on a Surface pro using a cable:

Essentially the Visual Studio debugger wants to debug your application via a network, so you are creating a network between your desktop machine and your surface pro.

Below is the guide with the main steps highlighted

https://tomsoderling.github.io/Wired-Debugging-on-Surface/

> **Hardware Needed**
>
> In order to debug over a wired connection, you’ll need a few things:
>
> - 2 USB to Ethernet dongles. You can find them for pretty cheap on
>   Amazon.
> - A length of cat 5 cable to connect the two dongles together.
>
> Connect the dongles together with the ethernet cable, and plug one
> dongle into your laptop and the other into the Surface.

Launch the remote debugger program on your surface and configure the following:

> **No Authentication**
>
> Turning this off seems to alleviate a lot of the
> hassle of trying to get the debugger to connect to the remote client
> app. I debug on a private or wired network and only have the remote
> client running when I need to debug, so the lack of security doesn’t
> concern me here.
>
> **Allow any user to debug**
>
> I use this setting because
> don’t log into my Windows 10 VM via Parallels so I’ve had an issue
> with that. I also use this when my coworker needs to debug on the
> Surface.

And then your device should be found in the Auto discover in visual studio